# Eclipse Helios random crashes

Tags: eclipse, crash, eclipse-3.6, helios

My Eclipse is crashing almost every 10 minutes and I have no idea why. It is so annoying. And I have no clue how to solve this problem.There is nothing specific I do to bring eclipse to crash. Sometimes I just open a new window or click on Save, etc. Here the error log:

```
Message: Unhandled event loop exception
```

and the Exception Stack Trace:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4083)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3969)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:715)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:531)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem.setEnabled(ToolItem.java:842)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer.updateBackNextBusy(BrowserViewer.java:292)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.BrowserViewer$6.changed(BrowserViewer.java:414)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Safari.webView_identifierForInitialRequest_fromDataSource(Safari.java:1150)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Safari.browserProc(Safari.java:372)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.OS.objc_msgSend_bool(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.cocoa.NSRunLoop.runMode(NSRunLoop.java:42)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sleep(Display.java:4200)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopIdle(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:364)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.eventLoopIdle(IDEWorkbenchAdvisor.java:887)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2641)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

My infos:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/jcdmb/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -keyring /Users/jcdmb/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Any clue/help? Thanks.

Comment: I have switched to Eclipse Indigo but the same problem persists.

Comment: You could also post back what, if anything, resolved or ameliorated this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen some reports of crashes with 64 bit versions of Eclipse, but crashing every 10 minutes is a bit severe. Why don't you open a bug against SWT (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform) and also attach any crash logs that you have.